# nodejs express postgresql create use in db user table

Tags: node.js, restful-authentication, node-postgres

What is a practical way to check if a user is already in the db before trying to insert the information for a "new user"

Here is my get user by id and insert function:

```
const getUserById = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.attuid)

    pg.query('SELECT * FROM geodate.users WHERE attuid = $1', [attuid], (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}


const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const attuid = request.body[0].attuid

    pg.query('INSERT INTO geodata.users (attuid, num_queries,created_date,modified_date) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *', [attuid, 0, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.rows[0].attuid}`)
    })
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rf guy,
Nice shades. First select the user from the geodata.users table. If the user exists, you should not add the user. I don't use pg to query postgres, so I really don't know how it works, but you should be able to do this:

```
const createUser = (request, response) => {   const attuid = request.body[0].attuid

  pg.query('SELECT * FROM geodate.users WHERE attuid = $1', [attuid], (err, res)=> {
    if (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
      if(results.rows > 0)
      {

        pg.query('INSERT INTO geodata.users (attuid, num_queries,created_date,modified_date) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING
*', [attuid, 0, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())], (error, results) => {
          if (error) {
              throw error
          }
          response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.rows[0].attuid}`)
      })

      }
      else{
    response.status(200).json({"message": "Ha! you are already in the db, silly"})
      } }) }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Daniel. I updated my code above with my `getuserbyid` function. How do I call that before trying to insert the user?

Comment: That works perfect for what I need. Thank you. I was definitely over thinking it.

Comment: @rfguy ya, overthinking happens alot in this biz.